# Which of the given samples will have the largest number of atoms?

Tags: physical-chemistry

The samples that we have in question are as follows:

1. 1g Au
2. 1g Na
3. 1g Li
4. 1g Cl2

I know that the sample of element which has the largest number of moles of atoms of the element must have the largest number of atoms.

I am also aware of the following formula:

n = m/M

where n stands for the number of moles of the substance, m stands for its mass and M denotes its molar mass.

Can I argue that **the number of moles of atoms in a given mass of an element is inversely proportional to its molar mass**, and use this fact in the solution of this problem?

Comment: Using "mass/amount of substance" is preferred to using "number of kilograms/moles of substance".

Comment: Yes. your reasoning is correct. One mass unit (gram or kilogram) of small objects contains more objects than the same mass of heavy objects.

Comment: Basically, the question is like If there is more stones in 10 kg of smaller stones or in 10 kg of bigger stones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your analogy is correct. The amount of substance $n$ is inversely proportional to molar mass $M$ $(n = m/M).$ Because the mass $m$ is fixed, increasing molar mass will lead to heavier atoms, reducing the number of atoms present in that fixed mass.
So, the answer to the question is *lithium* since it has the smallest molar mass among the listed compounds.